# Linked List class definition

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
using namespace std;    
class Node
{
     public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
    Node(int d){
        data=d;
        next=NULL;
    }
};
class Solution{
public:        
  Node* insert(Node *head,int data)
  {
      if(head == NULL){
          head = new Node(data);
          return head;
      }
      else if(head->next == NULL){
          Node *temp = new Node(data);
          head->next = temp;
          return head;
      }
      else{
          insert(head->next, data);
      }
      return head;
  }
        void display(Node *head)
  {
      Node *start=head;
      while(start)
      {
          cout<<start->data<<" ";
          start=start->next;
      }
  }
 };
 int main()
{
Node* head=NULL;
Solution mylist;
int T,data;
cin>>T;
while(T-->0){
    cin>>data;
    head=mylist.insert(head,data);
}   
mylist.display(head);
```

}

While defining the Node for a linked list why do we put a pointer in front of the class
i.e what does the statement `Node* insert(Node *head,int data)` do and what would happen if instead if I define it as `Node insert(Node *head,int data)`?

Comment: What holds you back from trying it yourself and seeing what happens? :)

Comment: One returns a *pointer* to the node, the other returns a *copy* of the node.  A rule of thumb is to pass large objects by pointer or reference.  Also linked lists use pointers instead of passing objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to return the pointer to the start of the list. An empty list is one where `head` points to `NULL` (C) or `nullptr` (C++), which both mean zero. When the memory of the first element is allocated and the Node is added, the address of that element is returned so that the main function can track the list's memory location.

If the list is emptied one element at a time, eventually the last call to the (hypothetical) `delete` function will return 0 to signal that the list is empty again.

If we were to return the element directly using `Node insert(Node n, int data)` the function would return a copy of the node instead of the actual node. That could *maybe* work provided that the function is modified as well, as the Node still has pointers inside it, but usually pointers are used.

If you were to just change the definition of the function to `Node insert(Node *n, int data)` the code in all likelyhood wouldn't compile, as the head is of type Node *.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. Perhaps you missed the recursion?

Comment: @user4581301 I answered why we return pointers, the recursion can be swapped with while loops and so is not essential. Also, if returning the element itself works in main, it must work with a properly modified insert as well. The second question is also answered now.